# Why does "if 0;" not work in shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I wrote the following shell script, just to see if I understand the syntax to use if statements:

```
if 0; then
        echo yes
fi
```

This doesn't work. It yields the error

```
./iffin: line 1: 0: command not found
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you type `0` at the shell prompt? What do you conclude from this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use

```
if true; then
        echo yes
fi
```

if expects the return code from a command. `0` is not a command.  `true` is a command.

The bash manual doesnt say much on the subject but here it is:
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs

You may want to look into the `test` command for more complex conditional logic.

```
if test foo = foo; then
        echo yes
fi
```

AKA

```
if [ foo = foo ]; then
        echo yes
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

To test for numbers being non-zero, use the arithmetic expression:

```
 if (( 0 )) ; then
     echo Never echoed
 else
     echo Always echoed
 fi
```

It makes more sense to use variables than literal numbers, though:

```
count_lines=$( wc -l < input.txt )
if (( count_lines )) ; then
    echo File has $count_lines lines.
fi
```

Comment: The portable way (since 1970) would be to `if test -ne 0; then ...` Arithmetic expressions with `(())` are a fancy-schmanzy new invention of creeping featurism :-) There's a `checkbashisms` program around so everybody can steer clear of portability pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the `bash` man page:

```
if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi

  The if list is executed.  If its exit status is zero, the then list is executed.
  Otherwise, each elif list  is  executed  in  turn, and if its exit status is zero,
  the corresponding then list is executed and the command completes.
  Otherwise, the else list is executed, if present.
  The exit status is the exit status of the last command executed,
  or zero if no condition tested true.
```

Which means that argument to `if` gets executed to get the return code, so in your example you're trying to execute command `0`, which apparently does not exist.

What does exist are the commands `true`, `false` and `test`, which is also aliased as `[`. It allows to write more complex expressions for `if`s. Read `man test` for more info.